# Should I fertilize young mango and avocado trees which have stopped growing?

Tags: fruit-trees, tree-care, fertilizer, avocado

I have a few mango and avocado trees. They are between 5 and 6 months old. They appear to have stopped growing. Should I fertilize them, or is it too early?  If it is too early for fertilization, what can I use to feed them in the mean time? When I seeded them, I added them to the soil with no other ingredients.

[image: Here is a picture of the avocado.]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Need some clarification please - first, where are you in the world, second, are these plants in pots outdoors or in the ground?

Comment: I just started some mango seeds and I'm curious about this question too!

Comment: I've tried to add pictures on my cell, but it refused to load them. Once I get home, I'll add some.

Comment: How deep are those pots (in inches) and what part of the world are you in?

Comment: I live in zone 10a, central Florida. These containers are about 14 inches deep.

Comment: What sort of soil did you use?  A freely draining potting mix or just local soil? Can you remove them from their pots and look at the roots?

Comment: I used nature's care organic soil. I presume that I can remove them and look at the root without damaging them.

Comment: I'd suggest that since both trees are suffering, then you've used the wrong material for potting these trees, and their roots are suffering.  So, pull them out to have a look to see if they're rotting or something else is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest that since both trees are suffering, then you've used the wrong material for potting these trees, and their roots are suffering.  So, pull them out to have a look to see if they're rotting or something else is wrong. It's highly unlikely they've exhausted the nutrients in their pots.

And be careful. My avocados came with a warning not to remove by holding the stem when removing from their pots. So it will probably be a two person job to remove them to examine the roots.

Answer (score 3):

You don't say where you are geographically but, most of us are having winter right now. In such case they should be at rest. If you are in the southern U S I would wait until late March before doing anything. Just stick with moderate watering for now. They may have had a bit of cold damage. If you are experiencing freezes I would bring them inside during the freeze return them to there places when it passes. Hold of fertilizing until growth resumes.

Comment: Based upon the coments and answers, I am going to move them into much larger containers. I'll keep an eye on them and see how they've progressed.

Answer (score 2):

Well, given where you are, its whatever passes for winter in your part of the world. Do not fertilize at this time of year, even in warmer regions, growth will slow or stop winter.

Although you've said the pots are 14 inches deep, I can see that they are not all full to the top with potting medium, which reduces the amount of root room available, so I'm not sure that isn't causing a problem. I note you say you used Nature's Care Organic Soil - is that what you actually mean, because that particular formulation isn't meant for potting plants? They also sell Nature's Care Organic Potting Soil, so if you used that, it should be fine. However, if you actually used the non potting version of this product, it likely isn't the ideal potting medium.